# How to check if field is required in blade template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-validation

I'm using classic validation rules in my controller:

```
$request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|min:5'
        ],
```

How can I check in blade templete if field 'name' is required?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input data-required="" type="text" name="name">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
    $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        noErrors = true;
        $.each($('form [data-required]'), function(index, element) {
            if($(element).val() == '') {
                noErrors = false;
                $(element).css('border', '1px solid red');
            } else {
                $(element).css('border', 'unset');
            }
        });

        if(noErrors) {
            $(this).trigger('submit');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Of course you can play around what happen to the element style or to add some other validation in front-end.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the error message using `$errors` variable in your blade file for the `'name'` field.

The `$errors` variable is bounded to the view by the `Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession middleware`, which is provided by the `web middleware` group.

When this middleware is applied an `$errors` variable will always be available in your views

For More: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the following code inside your form to check the validation error:

```
@if(count($errors))

<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>

        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)

        <li>{{ $error }}</li>

        @endforeach

    </ul>

</div>

@endif
```

Or do you want to check if 'name' field required in the front-end, before it comes to the Controller function at back-end? If you want to do that, you need to use some javascript code there for checking